# Print Django model data as JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have printed a for loop as below in my HTML Template:

```
                <td> 
                {% for athlete in booking.athlete.all %}
                {{athletes.id}}
                {% endfor %}
                </td>
```

The Output in HTML is as below.

```
<td> 
                
                1
                
                2
                
                3
                
                </td>
```

Is it possible to get the output to appear as [ "1", "2", "3" ], so we can then use this as a JS array or object?

I have tried a few things from the Django Template but it does not remove the additional white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a custom template tag to get the list of `athlete.ids`, and then the built-in [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter to render those ids as json.

Let's assume your app name is `myapp`.  If you don't have any custom filters yet, create the directory `myapp/templatetags/`, and add an empty `__init__.py` file.  Then in the file `myapp/templatetags/myapp_filters.py` add:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def qs_to_id_list(qs):
    return list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

In your template example, you would do:

```
{% load myapp_filters %}
{% for booking in bookings %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{booking.id}}</td>
    <td>{{booking.program_type}}</td>
    <td>{{booking.booking_time}}</td>

    {# set a unique script id for easier access in javascript #} 
    {% with script_id='athletes-data-'|add:booking.id %}
        {{booking.athlete.all|qs_to_id_list|json_script:script_id}}
    {% endwith %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The `json_script` filter will render a block like this (in each table row):

```
<script id="athletes-data-5" type="application/json">[1, 2, 3]</script>
```

which can be accessed in your client-side javascript.

Comment: Thanks Taherh, for the help. I tried your suggestion above but I get the following error "AttributeError at /admin_bookings/
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'values_list'". The Model I am working with is called Bookings and that has a Many to Many relationship named athlete, which connects to the Athlete Model.

Comment: I updated the answer to match the call pattern in the question, it should probably work now.

Comment: Think we are nearly there with this now. I have added in my View and HTML. Now it loops through the data correctly but prints the same athlete.id. Currently it prints the id [2] (See Script output rather than [1,2,3]

Comment: I rewrote the answer to reflect your updated question. You do not need to add anything to your view, you can remove that. Instead you can use the custom filter to get the list of ids that can be passed to `json_script`.

Comment: Thanks Taherh, I have edited the question to remove the updates. Just working on registering the template tag, as it keeps saying 'advancement_filters' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

Comment: Your `myapp/templatetags/` directory needs to have an empty `__init__.py` file in it, if you haven't added that yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244968/discussion-between-taherh-and-mark).

Comment: Got this working, using your answer above.  My fault had the template tags folder under the wrong directory. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate the continuous support on this issue.